# Translation of "coach mark"

Tags: traduction

What's the translation of “coach mark" in French?

“Coach mark" in English [can be defined as follows](https://uxframework.pearson.com/c/coachmarks) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201203231720/https://uxframework.pearson.com/c/coachmarks)):

> Coach marks [a user interface elements that] call attention to new or unique features, nudge users in the right direction, or guide users during onboarding.

Examples:

[image]

More examples from https://www.mobile-patterns.com/coach-marks ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201203232934/https://www.mobile-patterns.com/coach-marks), [mirror 2](https://archive.vn/im4JF)):

[image]

---

What I have tried:

- https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=coach+mark doesn't give any interesting translations.
- Wikipedia has no entry for coach marks.
- [Google translate translates coach mark into marque d'entraîneur](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=fr&text=coach%20mark&op=translate), which sounds like a too literal translation and I don't see "marque d'entraîneur" being used anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about how coach-marks differs from tooltips but I would call what you show one of:

> ***Bulle d'information***

> ***Bulle informative***

> ***Infobulle***

Note that *bulle* means here the usually rounded background of the text area used to show the piece of information with the triangle pointing to the location it refers like comics "speech balloons". Its technical name is *[phylactère](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylact%C3%A8re_(bande_dessin%C3%A9e))* but it is extremely rare and unknown by most of us.

In some of the new examples you added, the text has no specific background and is just overlaid to the main picture.

In that case *bulle* would be less suitable and you can call the thing ***une annotation***.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of a coach-mark, since it can have a close icon or a dismissal link, it seems from [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_chart_add_tooltips_markers_to_data_points.htm&type=5) that "marker" and "coach-mark" are synonymous.

According to the explanations on this same page the simple term "**marqueur**"  (marker), which is opposed to "info-bulle" (tooltip) can be used to translate "marker" or "coach-mark".

However, I cannot find any more information to corroborate this equivalence of terms.